# .NET Core Authorization Model: Policies that require context from the request

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-authorization

I've just started looking at the .NET Core security model.  It seems far and away better than previous models (I really like the policy idea, the roles were very limiting IMO) but the documentation doesn't seem to cover what I'd like to do... I'm hoping what I'd like to do is possible, but I don't know if it is.

I am building an application where users can create "organizations", and invite other users to join.  Conversely, users can apply to join an organization.

The organization is a central concept of the application; almost all activity is organization-centric, and I would like to build a policy that upon receiving a request, will verify that the current user has access to the organization resource he or she is asking for, as a member.  I would include an organization id with each request.

The problem I'm seeing, is that there doesn't seem to be any way to make a policy "aware" of the context of the request, so that it can examine the organization id and verify the user is a member of that organization.  Does such a mechanism exist, or is the policy concept not a good fit for this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IHttpContextAccessor, inject it where ever you want and use it to get context.

In your Startup.cs:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

And injection:

```
public class CustomClass 
{
     private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

     public CustomClass(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) 
     {
           _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
     }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the HttpContext is available through the context.Resource already.  Problem is, this seems to occur before any model binding or validation.  Ugh, this is just as ugly as AuthorizationActionFilters.